# Playing different landing animations depending on a float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add different landing animations to my third person controller, but I'm not sure how to code a float timer. This is what I have got so far. I was thinking of a float called airTime, and adding it to my groundCheck. The value of this float should go up when the player is not grounded, and when the player is grounded again this timer should reset.

The code I have thusfar:

```
private float airTime = 0f;

if (GroundCheck())
{
    // The airTime timer should be reset here?
    velocityY = 0;
    if (airTime > 10f) // I think, this should be in frames?
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("HardLanding");
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("NormalLanding");
    }
}
else
{
    anim.SetTrigger("onAir");
    // The airTime timer should start counting in frames
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i understand your question. You want to know how long the character was in the air?

Where is your code example, is this in the Update method which is called every frame? If you are working with update then you could add Time.deltaTime to your timer each frame when you are in the air, because it returns the time (in seconds) since the last frame.

Or you could also use the Time.time property which returns  the time in seconds since the start of the game.

Then when you start to go in the air you could store the Time.time in a float field, for example call it "airStartTime".

Then when you want to land you can use Time.time again and caculcate the difference, Time.time - airStartTime would return the amound of seconds that you were in the air.

But im not sure if that is what you want.

Edit:

```
private float airTime = 0f; // put this variable as a field of your class
// Since this check is done every Update you can add the delta time to the airTime variable
if (GroundCheck())
{
     // The airTime timer should be reset here?
     velocityY = 0;
     if (airTime > 10f) // I think, this should be in frames? -> the airTime will be in seconds with this method
     {
         anim.SetTrigger("HardLanding");
     }
     else
     {
         anim.SetTrigger("NormalLanding");
     }

     // Reset the time after the checks
     airTime = 0f;
}
else
{
    anim.SetTrigger("onAir"); // -> Currently this is set at every frame as long as the controller is in the air, 
    //you might need a additional check if you only want to set the trigger once when the character leaves the ground

    // The airTime timer should start counting in frames

    // Add the delta time here
    airTime += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: The example code is indeed in the update function. What I'm trying to do is check how long the player is not grounded, and this should lead to different landing animations, a hard landing, and a normal landing. I don't have alot of experience with coding, so I have no idea how to code this.

Comment: I assume that your "GroundCheck" method returns true if you are on the ground and otherwise false. And since you are calling this in the update method it does this check every frame, so your else part is executed every frame as soon as you are in the air and every frame until you are on the ground again, that means you can just put airTime += Time.deltaTime; in your else, then it will add up the counter every frame, but this also means that your anim.SetTrigger("onAir") is called every frame as long as you are in the air, is this what you want/need?

Comment: I'm not sure if the onAir trigger should be set every frame? You are right about the groundCheck btw. I was initially using a bool that was set to true: anim.SetBool("onAir", true);

Comment: That depends on your animator/animation, if the animation works as you expect it to look, then you can leave it as it is, but if the animator does something that you don't expect then you might have to add an additional check to only set the trigger when you leave the ground. I edited my answer to show you a timer example.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, I will give it a try when I get home!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot!